# How to access for loop externally and make it stop in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this function to make the text write letter by letter:

```
extension SKLabelNode {

func setTextWithTypeAnimation(typedText: String, characterInterval: NSTimeInterval = 0.05) {
    text = ""
    self.fontName = "PressStart2P"
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
        for character in typedText.characters {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.text = self.text! + String(character)
            }
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(characterInterval)
        }
    }
}
```

And, if the user clicks the screen, I want to make the for loop stop and show the complete text instantly.

Comment: what about a `boolean flag` that set to some value when user touch the screen and put a checking if statement inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var ignoreSleeper = false    

@IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {
        ignoreSleeper = true
}

extension SKLabelNode {

func setTextWithTypeAnimation(typedText: String, characterInterval: NSTimeInterval = 0.05) {
    text = ""
    self.fontName = "PressStart2P"
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
        for character in typedText.characters {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.text = self.text! + String(character)
            }
            if(!ignoreSleeper){
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(characterInterval)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** like @Breek already mentioned

Comment: This code starts a new thread which starts `count(typedText)` threads. I call this kind of approach "through the chest into the eye".
I'd suppose to implement a tiny `Timer` with a counter for the number of chars to display. Start the `Timer` with a repeat count of `count(typedText)` and the desired delay and you're good to go (with one thread). You can stop this timer at any time with a button press.

Writing this I realize this should be an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: Yes maybe that would be the better solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to implement a tiny `NSTimer` with a counter for the number of chars to display. Start the Timer with a repeat count of `typedText.characters.count` and the desired delay and you're good to go (with one thread). Increment the number of chars counter on each timer loop. You can stop this timer at any time with a button press by calling `invalidate` on the timer.

**Example**

```
var timer: NSTimer?
var numberOfCharsToPrint = 1
let text = "Hello, this is a test."

func updateLabel() {
    if numberOfCharsToPrint == text.characters.count {
        welcomeLabel.text = text
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    let index = text.startIndex.advancedBy(numberOfCharsToPrint)
    welcomeLabel.text = text.substringToIndex(index)

    numberOfCharsToPrint++;
}
```

Then initialize your timer whenever you want the animation to start.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, selector: "updateLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You can invalidate/stop the timer at any given time with `timer?.invalidate()`.

Comment: Yes of course. My Mac is at work. At home I have a PC. So you'll have to wait a couple of hours.